# Run batch script on a remote server (windows 7) from jenkins(windows server 2008)

Tags: batch-file, deployment, jenkins, psexec, jenkins-cli

I created a CI(jenkins) environment on windows server 2008. Now I want to execute windows batch command to remote to another windows(win7) and run a bat file on win7.

The batch command is:
PsExec.exe -accepteula \machinename -u username -p password cmd /c c:\test\test.bat

Jenkins console output is:
PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

The remote procedure call failed and did not execute.
Connecting to ...

Starting PSEXESVC service on ...

Could not start PSEXESVC service on :
Connecting to ...

Starting PSEXESVC service on ...

---

The batch command can be executed successfully by CMD, why failed on jenkins command?

I checked Remote Procedure Call(RPC) and Remote Procedure Call(RPC) Locator have been started in services.msc list.

I did a large of research by google, and spent the whole day to fix the issue. However I still haven't figured out how to fix the issue.

Any help is appreciated and will respond quickly to any suggestions, thanks!

Comment: Does `c:\test\test.bat` exist on **remote** machine?

Comment: Yes, it exists on remote machine. I can ran the command successfully by windows command line on the jenkins server(windows server 2008)  . PsExec.exe -accepteula \machinename -u username -p password cmd /c c:\test\test.bat

Comment: See if this helps: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/96decbd7-16eb-44a7-aa64-5ab1eeff976a/could-not-start-psexec-service-on-target-machine-access-is-denied?forum=w7itprogeneral